# How do I columnwise reduce a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
    from functools import reduce

import pandas as pd
from numpy import uint8, logical_or

df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""a    b    c
1   0   0
1   1   1
0   1   1
1   1   0"""), sep="\s+", dtype=uint8, header=0)
```

How do I columnwise reduce the dataframe?

Currently I just put all the vectors in a list and reduce it, but this cannot be the most pandastic way of doing it:

```
gene_vectors = [df[v] for v in df]

print(reduce(logical_or, gene_vectors))
```

Any alternatives?

Comment: You mean something like `df.apply(lambda x: reduce(np.logical_or, x))`?

Comment: Yeah that is probably it. Wonder whether my or that method is quickest....

Comment: Well all you're doing is creating a df for each column which seems unncessary, semantically they should perform the same, `apply` on a df calls the function on each column in turn (as `axis=0` is the default param value)

Comment: I think you want to set axis=1 to reduce the columns ```df.apply( lambda cols: reduce(logical_or, cols) ,axis=1)```

Comment: @dermen `axis=1` means row=wise here

Comment: yea, you compare row val with row val, however you reduce it over all columns, right ?

Comment: ```LO(LO(df.a[0], df.b[0]),df.c[0])``` should be the first element, which is what you get with axis=1.

Comment: If you're only looking to reduce based on column-wise `OR`, you could actually do `df.any(1)` I suppose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this is the "pandastic" way to achieve this

```
df.apply(lambda x: reduce(logical_or,x), axis=1)
```

although there might be other routes.