# Calculate "energy" of columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I try to calculate the signal energy of my `pandas.DataFrame` following this [formula for discrete-time signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing)). I tried with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and `applymap`, also with reduce, as suggested here: [How do I columnwise reduce a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872693/how-do-i-columnwise-reduce-a-pandas-dataframe) . But all I tried resulted doing the operation for each element, not for the whole column.

This not a signal processing specific question, it's just an example how to apply a "summarize" (*I don't know the right term for this*) function to columns.

My workaround, was to get the raw `numpy.array` data and do my calculations. But I am pretty sure there is a pandatic way to do this (and surly a more numpyic way).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = np.array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
              [0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, 8, -9],
              [0, 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7, -8, 9]]).transpose()
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

energies = []

# a same as d
a = df.as_matrix()
assert(np.array_equal(a, d))

for column in range(a.shape[1]):
    energies.append(sum(a[:,column] ** 2))

print(energies) # [40, 285, 285]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following for dataframe output -

```
(df**2).sum(axis=0) # Or (df**2).sum(0)
```

For performance, we could work with array extracted from the dataframe -

```
(df.values**2).sum(axis=0) # Or (df.values**2).sum(0)
```

For further performance boost, there's `np.einsum` -

```
a = df.values
out = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',a,a)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [31]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(1000,30)))

In [32]: %timeit (df**2).sum(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 518 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit (df.values**2).sum(0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.2 µs per loop

In [34]: def einsum_based(a):
    ...:     a = df.values
    ...:     return np.einsum('ij,ij->j',a,a)
    ...: 

In [35]: %timeit einsum_based(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: Really, that's it? Looks so simple, I'm feeling kind of dumb now :) Thank you!

Comment: `einsum` is for the nerdy ones, isn't it? But still a cool thing.

Comment: @ppasler Yeah the ones that form a club at the end, not the music one ;)

Comment: Unexpected how `numpy` is more than 10 times faster than `pandas`. Could be the `C` implementation?

Comment: @ppasler Not an expert on pandas, so can't comment on that authoritatively, but working with arrays is mostly the more performant one than the dataframe data based on some of the pandas based questions that I was able to answer with NumPy methods using the underlying array data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DataFrame.pow`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html) with [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
print (df.pow(2).sum())
0     40
1    285
2    285
dtype: int64

print (df.pow(2).sum().values.tolist())
[40, 285, 285]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a property `df.var()` which returns variance of the columns. Which is energy (dependent on definition, you might need to multiply it by the number of elements `df.var()*df.shape[0]`).

Comment: Thanks, this gives quite equal results as my formula. As I wonder how to do such functions in general, this is only valid for my special case.